# Command with navigation to another page

Tags: xamarin.forms

i need to redirect to another page in ViewModel after performing some action. I have button and set my command, however if i load the page fort the first time then i get an error "Please use navigation page" application fails and i start it again and try to load the page and it works, but if i delete the app from emulator and try all over again i have the same process.

```cs
public ICommand FilterItemsCommand { get; private set; }
public FilterArticlesForPurchaseViewModel()
    : base()
{    
    Task.Run(async () => await LoadAllDataForArticlesAndCategories()).Wait();

    FilterItemsCommand = new Command(async () => await FilterItems());
}
private async Task FilterItems() 
{ 
    await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new ArticlesForPurchaseFiltered());
}
```

App

```cs
MainPage = new NavigationPage(GetMainPage());
```

I have also tried this

```cs
Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new ArticlesForPurchaseFiltered());
```

But then i cant go back to previous page and if i use android back button the application fails
BTW i am using master detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `INavigation navigation` to your ViewModel's constructor like following code.

```cs
public ItemsViewModel(INavigation navigation)
{
    Title = "Browse";
    Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
    LoadItemsCommand = new Command(async () => await ExecuteLoadItemsCommand());
    FilterItemsCommand = new Command(() => { navigation.PushModalAsync(new Page1()); });
    MessagingCenter.Subscribe<NewItemPage, Item>(this, "AddItem", async (obj, item) =>
    {
        var newItem = item as Item;
        Items.Add(newItem);
        await DataStore.AddItemAsync(newItem);
    });
}
```

When you binding the viewmodel, you can add the attribute like following code.

```cs
public ItemsPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    BindingContext = viewModel = new ItemsViewModel(Navigation);
}
```

If you want to achieve the navigation in the viewModel, you can use

```cs
// this way you need add `MainPage =new NavigationPage( new MainPage());` in app.xaml.cs
 navigation.PushAsync(new Page1());
```

```cs
// this way you do not need `MainPage =new NavigationPage( new MainPage());` in //app.xaml.cs, just used it directly
 navigation.PushModalAsync(new Page1());
```

Comment: Ok waitting for your update. If the reply is helpful, please accept it as answer(click the “✔” in the left upper corner), it will help others who have similar issue.